# How to detect POS transaction in Android Wallet Application?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am developing Android Wallet application using SEEK API and NFC. I have the Visa applet installed in the Sim card. My question is, How to detect if a successful/unsuccessful contact is made to the POS terminal? Is there any Intent Action available in Android that I can put in some activity or some receiver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I Found the way of detecting POS terminal transaction. The NFC API, TRANSACTION_DETECTED is hidden. When transaction is there, TagDetectedActivity will launch.

`<activity android:name=".TagDetectedActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_DETECTED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="nfc" android:host="secure" android:port="0" android:pathPrefix="/axxxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="nfc" android:host="secure" android:port="0" android:pathPattern="/.*/axxxxx.*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: I'm using off host emulation.I'm trying to grab the transaction event.But the activity is not receiving the event in this way.Can you please tell me more about this?

Comment: Hi @RabbyAlam, Can you put your source code? My code is working.

Comment: Hello @abhi , here is my xml file.[link] (http://www.codeshare.io/acnBt)
I dont have any real POS machine.I'm using omnikey contactless reader  to send apdu to the card and simulate transaction.